# What are practical applications of the AO* algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

Those who have worked or working in artificial intelligence(or equivalent) area should be knowing the AO* algorithm very well.

Its pretty clear that it is a generalized algorithm.

Do anybody of you have come across any practical application of the AO* algorithm?Some of you might already have worked on it.

So it would be great if you can share your thoughts or experience on AO* algorithm, how it can actually be used practically. what is the power of it?

Those who don't know the AO* algorithm, can refer following pdf (size -291 KB)

[Generalized AO* algorithm](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/papers/kumar85generalization.pdf)

Comment: then it's not so famous.

Comment: Isn't this just a search algorithm?  The only difference seems to be that branches can be or'ed and and'ed together.  This allows the search to be much quicker since you can easily eliminate branches on boolean logic, rather than computing heuristics and following false paths.

Comment: I just invented a famous algorithm that no one has ever thought of before

Comment: Fixed "famous". Be happy now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AO* has rarely been used in practical applications, to my knowledge. It is useful for searching game trees, problem solving etc. but in most cases more domain specific search algorithms (e.g. alpha-beta pruning for game trees, general or domain specific planning algorithms) are used instead.

In particular, AI uses knowledge-intensive approaches and in practical applications heavy use is made of domain specific knowledge or problem conditions to produce better (faster or more optimal solutions).

Game search is an example where full-breadth search is standard, but this may because of the small (relative to other domains) size of the search space. Even in game tree search, extensive use is made of problem specific features, i.e. often search is terminated only in quiescent states (i.e. not during a forced exchange or when there is a check).

In planning, often knowledge is used to guide a search of a generated solution space rather than doing a state space search. This gives non-optimal solutions but for many domains it yields reasonable solutions at much less cost.

Answer (score -4):

Assuming you're referring to A*, two good applications are searching game trees and finding routes in road maps.

Comment: A* and AO* are two different algorithms.You may be knowing it.

Comment: If AO* is a separate algorithm, then I don't think I'd call it famous.  I've never heard of it, and searching Google returns 30 times as many results for a* algorithm than ao* algorithm.